# Divide number into many unequal parts JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, division

I want to split a number between 20 and 50 into unequal parts.

For example:

30 = 1x20 & 1x10

45 = 2x20 1x5

or 38 = 1x20 1x10 1x5 1x2 1x1

```
document.getElementById("jscolor").style.color = "red";
var tokenResult = prompt(`Please enter a number between 10 and 50: `);
var divideBy = 5;
tokenResult = parseInt(tokenResult);
document.write(tokenResult + ` = `);
for (var i = 0; i < divideBy; i++) {
    document.write(`${tokenResult / divideBy} `);
}
```

Which outputs something like:

25 = 5 5 5 5 5

I haven't managed to split it into unequal parts that aren't random.

Comment: So there are tons of solutions for how to break it up. So what is the end goal?

Comment: It's an assignment for my JS class. The end goal is to tell the user the divided amount like the example in the post.

Comment: You said "split it into unequal parts that aren't random", if they aren't randomly split what sould be the rule that is followed ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify that. The number should be split once in parts of 20, 10, 5, 2, and 1 like the third example. It has to output like the third example as well.

Comment: Please consider reading [ask] to have a less frustrating experience here :) The term you probably want to google is "factorization" if you want its divisors (or google the coin/note problem). While I don't agree with Corey's tone I think it's important to struggle with these sort of issues when learning to code - they _are_ frustrating and the frustration shows you are putting in mental effort that helps you grow. This isn't intuitive when starting to learn so I think it's important to point out.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with random. That's why I said "parts that aren't random". I do understand what I have to do for this assignment. I just don't know how to do it. I even clarified it above your comment, except they're tokens instead of dollars but I didn't feel the need to go into that much detail.

Comment: Thanks for the help Benjamin. I'll look into factorization.

Answer (score 0):

Baically ou need an array of denominations, like

```
[20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
```

Then you need to take your value and divide it through the largest value. Take the count, an integer value and store it along with the denomination.

Substract the product of count and denomination value from the input value.

If your new value is not zero take the second large value from the denominations array and perfor the last steps again.

Finally get all counts and denominations into a readable string and make an output.